# Hdgs to be removed from the S&P/ASX Indices

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, stock-markets

I am new to stock trade and based on Sydney. Just bought some stock of Wotif last week. but yesterday heard of news saying,

> Sydney , October 8 , 201 4 : S&P Dow Jones Indices announced today
>   that it will removeWotif.com Holdings Limited (ASX:WTF)from the
>   S&P/ASX 200, subject to shareholder and final court approval of the
>   proposed scheme of arrangement under which the company will be
>   acquired by Expedia, Inc. S&P Dow Jones Indices will remove Wotif.com
>   Holdings Limited from the S&P/ASX 200 after the close of trading on
>   October 15,2014.
>
> Wotif.com Holdings Limited will be replaced by Healthscope Limited
>   (ASX:HSO) in the S&P/ASX 200 after the close of trading onOctober
>   15,2014

What does it really means?

Will i loose all the Wotif Stock or All the stocks will be transferred to Healthscope limited?

Comment: Read the newspapers. It looks like you'll get $3.30 per Wotif share.  http://www.smh.com.au/business/accc-clears-expedia-takeover-of-wotif-20141002-10p01r.html

Comment: Thanks peter. But that news was in last week.

Comment: So, the price won't change. The sale price has been agreed: you get cash of $3.30 per share you hold in Wotif.

Comment: Your confusion about Healthscope is indicative of a truly severe lack of understanding about markets, exchanges, and indexes.  I don't say this to be rude, but rather to encourage you to PLEASE do a lot more reading before putting any more money in the market.  You can find some helpful introductions at sites like [Marketwatch](http://www.marketwatch.com/getting-started) or [Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/university/stocks/).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, i understand and already started reading. I am not from a financial background but its not rocket science either. I didn't invest large amount just invested some money which i am comfortable if i happen to loose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the comments, from the SMH article, [you will get $3.30 per share you hold in Wotif.](http://www.smh.com.au/business/accc-clears-expedia-takeover-of-wotif-20141002-10p01r.html)

The bit about Wotif veing replaced in the S&P ASX200 index by another company has no impact on your shares in Wotif. It just means that the index (the amalgamation of 200 companies) will have one drop out (Wotif) and another replace it (Healthscope).